Ending thread when other 4 threads are running
My function aims to allow maximum 5 threads to run in the same time, and thread 10 can only end when there are exactly 5 threads running(including itself). For most cases it works as intended, but I believe the problem occurs when thread 10 remains the last thread in execution.
void *thread_function2(void *arg)
{
    THREAD *thread = (THREAD*)arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(thread->lock);
    while(active_threads >= 5)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(thread->cond, thread->lock);  
    }

    active_threads++;    //inseamna ca am inca un thread
    pthread_mutex_unlock(thread->lock);

    info(BEGIN, thread->procId, thread->threadId);    
    if(thread->threadId == 10)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(thread->lock);
        while(active_threads != 5 && remaining > 1)    //had to add remaining > 1, or else I would get time limit exceeded
            pthread_cond_wait(thread->cond, thread->lock);  
        pthread_mutex_unlock(thread->lock);    
    } 
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(thread->lock);                
    info(END, thread->procId, thread->threadId);
    active_threads--;
  remaining--;

    if(active_threads < 5)                         
    {
        pthread_cond_broadcast(thread->cond);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(thread->lock);
   
    
    return NULL;
}

The test that fails every time: Checking threads ...the following threads are running while ending thread T4.10: 10

The program is incomplete.

I've only posted the function,  in main I have created the threads and added the parameters which are sent to the function. I also checked if the threads are launched correctly, so the problem is somewhere inside the function.

See, the problem cannot be reproduced with only the function.
